# How do I get the String representation of a View's id

Tags: android, android-view, android-resources, android-identifiers

I have a `view` and i have it's resource id ( i.e. `R.id.xxx` ) and i want to extract the `xxx` part and convert it to a String.

Is that possible to do?

Just to be clear, I have `view.getId()` *a resource integer*, not the actual name of the id.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
View v;
String ResourceIdAsString = v.getResources().getResourceName(v.getId());
```

Use this in the view constructors

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
   getResources().getResourceEntryName(int resid);
```